Playwright - how to disable Dot reporter on CI
According to playwright docs about Dot reporter:

Dot reporter
Dot reporter is very concise - it only produces a single character per successful test run. It is the default on CI and useful where you don't want a lot of output.

So, as you can see, it's the default reporter on CI.
The problem is that I couldn't found any way to disable it,
I've tried to set another reporter and it didn't help, also tried to set multiple reporters, and still get those dots on CI logs.
I need a way to disable or even exclude it.
My reporters configuration:
reporter: process.env.CI ? [["blob"],["junit"],] : [["list"], ["html", { open: "on-failure" }]],

